# Python Tkinter: Pmw only works in IDLE / PyCharm

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, import, tkinter

I'm building a GUI program in Python 2.7, but never get the GUI window to show when double-clicking the .py file.

I believe I have narrowed the problem down to Pmw (Python megawidgets). If I run the following example code with "import Pmw" commented out, I can open the GUI by double-clicking the .py file. If I instead import Pmw I cannot open the GUI with a double-click. The exe window just flashes and goes immediately away. It does, however, work in both cases if I launch the program through PyCharm.

```
from sys import exit
from Tkinter import *
# import Pmw

root = Tk()
Button(root, text="Hello", command=exit).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I uninstalled and re-installed Pmw. This didn't help. 
I have searched Google for the better half of the day without finding anything related. 
I use Python 2.7 in Windows 7.

Comment: What exact error are you getting ?

Comment: I don't see any error. The exe window appears for a fraction of a second and then goes away. 

I started to suspect that the problem could be somehow related to Tkinter and tried to import a specific class from Pmw. When I typed "from Pmw import RadioSelect" PyCharm highlighted the class "RadioSelect" and gave me an "unresolved reference" notification. Could it be that the Pmw installation is still somehow unsuccessful?

Comment: this is because of PyCharm's a static analysis. i think u need to enable a few things at python debugger. Open Python debugger and check "Collect Run time types info for code insight"

Comment: I didn't quite understand your suggestion. I checked the box for "Collect Run time types info for code insight" in Python debugger.  The same problem exists.

Comment: okay.. try right click on the place (code) u are getting error & click "Ignore unresolved refernce-->suppress of the statement"

Comment: run code manually in cmd.exe - not by double-clicking - and maybe you see error message.

Comment: Still, I don't see how suppressing the unresolved reference statement can fix my problem. I gave the "unresolved reference" notification as a suggestion to find the source of my actual problem. The actual problem is that importing anything from Pmw will cause the code not to work outside PyCharm. If I just type "import Pmw" I don't get the notification but the program will still not run when double-clicking the .py file (outside PyCharm).

Comment: @furas - I tried your suggestion and ran the code in cmd. It runs normally there as well (so no error messages). It seems that the problem is narrowed down to double-clicking the .py file. Can it be that the double-clicking calls for another interpreter or something?  I did check that the "open with" refers to my Anaconda python.exe and not the basic Python 2.7 I also have installed.

Comment: every interpreter use own modules so you have to install Pmw for both interpreters. Basic Python use `pip` and Anaconda Python use `conda` to install modules. Or you can choose Anaconda Python in PyCharm and uninstall basic Python to have only one interpreter.

Comment: Okay, so earlier I installed the Pmw package with "pip install Pmw". If I type "conda list" in cmd it gives me all the packages installed in conda. Only the Pmw package is listed there as <pip>. I believe this is what @furas is referring to.  But I cannot understand why both the cmd and PyCharm are able to run the program and a "double-click" not. The double-click opens the Anaconda interpreter which has Pmw installed with pip - that is, the same interpreter which cmd and PyCharm use.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by uninstalling the basic Python 2.7 installation and leaving only the Anaconda installation on my computer.

Long story:
I had both the basic installation and an Anaconda installation of Python 2.7 on my computer. In PyCharm I had set the Anaconda installation as the project interpreter. Similarly, I had made a PATH variable to that installation. Therefore, when running the program in Pycharm or cmd it used the correct interpreter (which had Pmw installed).

When I double-clicked the program in a folder it used the basic installation as an interpreter. That failed, because the basic installation didn't have Pmw installed.

What bothers me still is that even if I right-clicked the program in a folder and chose the Anaconda installation's python.exe to run it it still failed.

Thanks @furas for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This was problem with me too it had hard task of installing "Pmw" package finally found the solution by anaconda cloud packages

> first get to ur anaconda cmd prompt.
>   then type -conda install -c fable pmw then enter.

it takes few time to complete the task once its done .
check the installation of the package in Ipython of anaconda by just typing

> help("modules")
>   and u will find the Pmw in the package list.

now u can import it by typing 
import Pmw